# Multiple simultaneous connections from excel vba to Access DB

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, adodb

I am building a somewhat complex Excel sheet for a bank, that uses an Access Database.

This sheet loads a ton of data to prebuilt sheets.
After that, they can run a few macros and add some inputs
In the end, I open a new connection to insert these inputs in different tables from the ones that where queried in the beginning

My problem is that when loading the information to the workbook, this action can only be performed by one user at a time.

When this process is running in one user computer other users get the error

> The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot open or write to
>   the file ''. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you
>   need permission to view and write its data.

I know the users have permission because once the process is done on user 1, user 2 has no problem.

I am using ADODB (connection, recordset and command) and this is the code I use about four different times for four different stored queries in access:

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection 
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset 
Dim cmd_apoio As New ADODB.Command

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = " & PV.dbpath

With cmd_apoio
    .ActiveConnection = cnn
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "tabela_apoio_entidades"
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("nip", adNumeric, adParamInput, 20)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("anomes", adNumeric, adParamInput, 20)
    .Parameters(0) = PV.nip_grupo
    .Parameters(1) = PV.ano_mes
End With

Set rs = cmd_apoio.Execute()
```

(the PV. variables are public variables declared in another module(PV))
Using this method is there a way to allow multiple connections at once?
Especially as this is only to retrieve information (read-only) and not to update any records in tables.

I am using Excel 2013 and Access 2013, the database is .accdb

**EDIT: The tables are linked tables to txt files (i think this might be important)**

Answer (score 1):

Try using `rs.Open` instead of `cmd.Execute`, and specify the lock type:

After your `End With`:

```
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open cmd_apoio, cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

Comment: i did this, removing the `Set rs = cmd_apoio.Execute()`

I get the error:
Runtime error '3707'
Cannot change the ActiveConnection property of a Recordset Object wich has a command object as its source

Comment: Remove `.ActiveConnection = cnn` and try again

Comment: still got the same error doing that, I the removed the cnn from the open statement like `rs.Open cmd_apoio, , adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic`
and kept the `.ActiveConnection = cnn`.
This works, as in it runs, but doesn't solve the multiuser problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your connection mode explicitly:

```
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
cnn.Mode = 16 + 3    'adModeShareDenyNone + adModeShareReadWrite   '
cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = " & PV.dbpath
```

See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/connectmodeenum

Comment: Do you get the same error?  If so, then it implies that someone/something else (or other code within the same app) has it open exclusively.

Comment: I still get the same error, the only objects that can create this error are adodb.Connection right? I use four of these on different macros, I always close them and all of them have this code implemented.

Comment: @JoelAlmeida Then something else must have the file open exclusively.  Do you have it open in the Access IDE?

Comment: No, the database file was closed when testing this.
The file is shared on a private network (of a bank), the PV.path is the path to the network folder/file of the access db. Could there be any limitations/security preventions from the network side preventing this?

The only connections I use have that setting `cnn.Mode = 16 + 3`

Comment: Make a local copy of the Access MDB that only you have/can access, then change your program to access that copy instead and see if it works then.  This should tell you if the problem is in your code or with the network/security.  (NOTE: do not open this copy with anything else before testing it with your program.  If you do, then restart your box before testing to insure that there is nothing in the background of your box locking it)

Comment: Can it be because I use linked tables to txt files?

Comment: @JoelAlmeida That's possible. If you suspect that, then you should debug the code and establish on exactly what line (and what file) the error is being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

I can only contribute the comments that I've always considered excel not to be multi user.

And in linking Excel to Access - which I've done a lot - the excel must always be closed when working from the Access side.  There cannot be a user directly in the Excel - it's role to Access is to behave like a table.

You are in the other direction in using Excel as the front end with Access tables linked - - but in terms of multi user I wonder if the situation is the same.

Comment: I think I fully understood your comment.

Although I'm using excel as front end to access it's mostly to read only info,
as the users never update the data from the queried tables, they only input some new values that get stored in different tables.
The data I show is only an accessory to the decision making process.
The only time I need it to be multiuser is when its loading the information (establishing the connection to present the data in Excel)
For the table inserts, I can simply check if the connection is clear and wait till it is, as this operation occurs less frequently.

Comment: So I may be out of date.  I did not think one could have multiple people working in the same excel workbook/file at the same time.  Especially in terms of entering/editing data.

Comment: that's just it, it's not the same file, it's copies of the same file stored locally on each individual computer, different workbooks connecting to the same db

Comment: ah ok.  So in a split multi user Access installation we can have multiple front end files connecting to the same single back end file, that just holds tables.  My only guess is that the back end thinks all your connections are from the same front end.  I don't have the experience to say as to whether your connection string can be crafted differently.

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same situation as you do, having excel as front-end connecting to data stored in Access.
I kind of solved this multi-user issue by establishing and closing connection on every single action taken by user.
It drags down performance a lot, but I guess it enables concurrent uses.

```
cnn.Close
Set cnn = Nothing
```